# How set correctly a JsonNode in Mongo but without set it like String using Jackson in Java?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson

I am receiving a Json response from my server

```
{
"results": [],
"metadata": {
    "total_hits": 0,
    "max_score": 0
 }
}
```

I work it on like a JsoNode

```
JsonNode rootNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(response);
...
```

and finally I return a String

```
Procces obj = processResponse(rootNode) // This method only make a Object with the value of rootNode
String proccesString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
return proccesString;
```

The problem is when I set it on my mongo database in the `MyProccesResponse` field, appear this:

```
{"MyProccesResponse": "{\"results\": [],\"metadata\": {\"total_hits\": 0, \"max_score\": 0}}"
```

}

and I need

```
{
  "MyProccesResponse": {
    "results": [],
    "metadata": {
        "total_hits": 0,
        "max_score": 0
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix It?

Comment: Can you add the code where you insert the document into the database (Mongo code)?

Comment: @JalalSordo Nothing of properties of ObjectMapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString()`, simply return the value of your `obj` variable, and MongoDB will do the serialisation to JSON for you.

Comment: My method now returned a String and returns an object, in this sense, is better than try to save an object in mongo